# Why is my component centering vertically on web view but not native view with react native / expo app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to centre my search component (horizontally and vertically) using flex. It works fine on the web view, but on the Native view it does not centre vertically. I am using expo which has several available methods to view the app:

[image: Screenshot of expo app output]

Here is the App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Search from './components/Search';

const styles: any = {
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    margin: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
}
const App = () => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} >
      <Search/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and here is Search.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

const Search = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timerId: any = null;
    if (searchTerm.length >= 2) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/search/${searchTerm}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setResults(data.results))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      }, 500);
    } else {
      setResults([]);
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={searchTerm}
        onChangeText={(text) => setSearchTerm(text)}
        placeholder="Search"
      />
      <FlatList
        data={results}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};


export default Search;
```

Comment: It's likely due to flex direction on mobile being different than on web. Try adding `flex-direction: row;` to your styles

Comment: didn't do anything but thankyou :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by setting the width of parent View in  Search.tsx to 100% and then adding an additional View component inside the container View inside  App.tsx.

Search.tsx changes

```
    <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
    <TextInput
      value={searchTerm}
      onChangeText={(text) => setSearchTerm(text)}
      placeholder="Search"
    />
    <FlatList
      data={results}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </View>
```

app.tsx changes

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View >
      <Search />
    </View>
  </View>
```

Shout out to ChatGPT for the solution (after some attempts)

Answer (score 0):

The wrapping View inside Search will span the whole screen and the list inside it will only take as much space as it needs. Apply flex: 1 to your flatlist or justifyItems: “center” to the wrapping view.

Comment: didn't work I'm afraid but thanks! :-)